# firefox version 50 not playing .mp3 that was converted using ffmpeg ver 3.1

Tags: firefox, ffmpeg, mp3

I am using "`ffmpeg version 3.1`" on my server. It have libavcodec version"`57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100`" in the ffmpeg software.

I am still facing the issue that mp3 is not playing in the firefox browser.

I am using this command to convert my .ogg and .wav files into mp3 files.

```
ffmpeg -i {$inputFilePath} -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 320 -f mp3 -write_xing 0 {$outputFilePath}
```

This is the outcome of "ffmpeg" on my server:

```
ffmpeg version N-80283-g84efdab Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
  libavformat    57. 37.101 / 57. 37.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.101 /  6. 46.101
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

I am unable to figure out what to do in order to fix this problem? I want the mp3 files to work as before firefox released version 50.

Comment: Plays fine here with Firefox 50. A small correction: you need to add a 'k' to your command: `-ab 320k`. Can you post one of your failing files somewhere online?

Comment: Also have a look in `about:config` of Firefox and change `media.libavcodec.allow-obsolete;false` to `media.libavcodec.allow-obsolete;true` and this may be enough...

Comment: @andrew.46 thanks for replying. About your first comment. I'll upload the file somewhere and add its link here. About your second comment, I have read this firefox fix online as well. But I can't tell all my customer (website users to do this). I can myself do this, but not to all the website users. I need to find the solution so that they don't have do anything but play the audio.

Comment: @andrew.46 Here is the link for current audio file. I recorded this sample file, you can find it here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/04kxq04unypxa1a/fit.mp3?dl=0

Comment: Here's another audio file with added 'k' in `-ab 320k` https://www.dropbox.com/s/3eezd7xpv93mwjy/sit.mp3?dl=0 this file also do not play without making setting in firefox browser.

Comment: I want to make setting in ffmpeg command so that firefox do not prevent it from playing in the browser. Firefox update say they have 'Blocked versions of libavcodec older than 54.35.1' but mp3 should work with 'libavcodec' version higher, my ffmpeg have 'libavcodec' version 57.46.1.

Comment: Oddly enough both of your files report from mediainfo as having been written by Lame rather than Lavf. Both play fine in Firefox 50 here. Try this file that I have created: http://www.andrews-corner.org/tmp/testing.mp3

Comment: Its working on firefox 50. What have you done in this file? How can i update my query to make such files. Initially i am converting .ogg / .wav file into .mp3 file on my server.

Comment: I used the git FFmpeg and omitted the `-write_xing 0 ` option. Try both of those options and see if the issue is rectified.